# Two iOS apps using a same CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

**Use Case:**

1. **App A** has a CoreData Model. It can read or write to the database.
2. **App B** now should be able to read the data from the same CoreData.

**Tried:**

For App A, I have a custom class `NSCustomPersistentContainer.swift`

```
class NSCustomPersistentContainer : NSPersistentContainer {

  override open class func defaultDirectoryURL() -> URL {

    var storeURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.identifier")
    storeURL = storeURL?.appendingPathComponent("MyModel.sqlite")

    return storeURL!
  }
}
```

And, `AppDelegate.swift` with :

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    
    let container = NSCustomPersistentContainer(name: "MyModel")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

This creates a Database that I can read or write in App A.

Now, how can I access that database from App B? I saw a lot of QA regarding shared container between app and extension, but how do I do with two apps?

Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I removed my answer, since you already using app groups. Yes, extension and app are the same as 2 apps in this case, as they each have a separate container, and then use shared group container to share the data. So your second app just needs to do the same ass the first one: join the same group, then read/write the same coredata